# setState() called in constructor: _ModalIngredientsState#60ddf(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)

Tags: flutter

I have a dialog and I need to open it with three buttons, when the dialog opens I have two buttons that close it and I need to go back to the Home screen, which is the screen that is overlaid by the dialog

```
    class ModalIngredients extends StatefulWidget {
      const ModalIngredients({Key key}) : super(key: key);
      showModalAddIngredients(BuildContext context) =>
          createState().showModalAddIngredients(context);
      @override
      _ModalIngredientsState createState() => _ModalIngredientsState();
    }
    
    class _ModalIngredientsState extends State<ModalIngredients> {
      TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
    
      showModalAddIngredients(context) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Adicionar Ingrediente'),
                content: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      valueText = value;
                    });
                  },
                  controller: _textFieldController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Ex: Trigo"),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Text('Cancelar'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Text('Salvar'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        codeDialog = valueText;
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            });
      }
    
      String codeDialog;
      String valueText;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container();
      }
    }
```

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
setState() called in constructor: _ModalIngredientsState#adab3(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
2

This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.

Comment: Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
setState() called in constructor: _ModalIngredientsState#adab3(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run your `showModalAddIngredients()` method because `showDialog` causes a rebuild of the current widget (in order to show a dialog widget).  You are not allowed call for a rebuild, *while* a build is currently happening.

You can use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` to perform some action **after** your hosting widget has completed its initial build/render.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// This allows you to do something after the initial build is complete
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) => showModalAddIngredients(context));
```

#### Full example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ModalIngredients extends StatefulWidget {
  //const ModalIngredients({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  /// Don't do this.  Generally, nothing goes into the StatefulWidget except
  /// final arguments to be used in the State<T> object
  /*showModalAddIngredients(BuildContext context) =>
      createState().showModalAddIngredients(context);*/
  @override
  _ModalIngredientsState createState() => _ModalIngredientsState();
}

class _ModalIngredientsState extends State<ModalIngredients> {
  TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();

  showModalAddIngredients(context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Adicionar Ingrediente'),
            content: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  valueText = value;
                });
              },
              controller: _textFieldController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Ex: Trigo"),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('Cancelar'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.green,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('Salvar'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    codeDialog = valueText;
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  String codeDialog;
  String valueText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// This allows you to do something after the initial build is complete
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) => showModalAddIngredients(context));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand, but how do I call the method on the other screen? I was doing like this ModalIngredients().showModalAddIngredients(context);

Comment: You're trying to use Flutter in an imperative way, with how you're describing and it's not working because Flutter is architected as a declarative framework.  Maybe this answer will help clarify: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66433631/2301224